# What is the practical difference between res.clearCookie() and req.session.destroy()?

Tags: node.js, express, express-session

I'm using `node.js`, with the `express` and `express-session` packages to test various CRUD implementations.

What is the practical difference between `res.clearCookie()` and `req.session.destroy()`?

Both code patterns below appear to accomplish the same thing, but I wonder if I'm missing something important.

**Code pattern 1:**

```
router.post('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    req.session.destroy( function(error) {
        if(error) {
            console.log(error);
        }
        res.redirect('/');
    });
});
```

**Code pattern 2:**

```
router.post('/logout', function(req, res, next) {
    res.clearCookie(SESSION_NAME);
    res.redirect('/');
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`res.clearCookie()` will just delete the cookie, and if you can somehow restore the cookie (if you had a backup or if someone stole it), you will log back in (or whatever the cookie's functionality was). If you use `req.session.destroy()`, the session will be invalidated in the server as well, so even if you got back the cookie you won't get back the session.